# How to arbitrarily exclude jar(s) from aar when building in gradle

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, aar

My AAR library includes multiple dependent libraries. However, there are some projects using the library do not need some dependent libs.
I want to exclude them from the built APK

This is my AAR file structure like this. I want to have a snippet of code excluding things like dagger-2.7.jar or eventbus-2.2.1.jar

By the way, I referred a post here but it doesn't work in my case: [Exclude jar-library from aar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38658378/exclude-jar-library-from-aar)

[image]

Thank you very much for your support!!!

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?